# How can i use awk to ignore a comma?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

How can I separate a comma using awk for the below

```
1, servername, url, Properties, hostname, version, os, application server.
```

I have saved the above line in a file called *test.properties* and using the following command

```
awk  '{ print $1 }' test.properties
```

and i just want the server name to be printed in the output, instead, it prints the whole line.

Should i use cut instead for situations like this?

Comment: Change to field separator to a comma `awk -F, 'yadayada'`

Comment: If your example prints the whole line, you have a much bigger issue as awk is broken.  Your example input should have printed '1,' (without quotes).  I would suggest reinstalling it prior to looking at any of the solutions provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
1, servername, url, Properties, hostname, version, os, application server
```

Just set the field separator properly to a comma:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk -F, '{print $1}'    
1
```

Or, as you say, use `cut`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | cut -d , -f1    
1
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I tried to use a field separator, but incorrectly. Here is what i did awk -F ',' '{print $1}'
~

Comment: Bashism for a quoted single character is `awk -F$','` but you don't need to quote in this case.

Comment: @dawg always quote your strings unless you have a specific reason not to, and use single quotes unless you need double. Quotes aren't something you add when you need to, they're something you **remove** when you need to. No need for any bashisms when setting `FS` as awk interprets escape sequences when setting variables on the command line. What @SGR29 had with `awk -F',' ...` was the best way to write that code and if it didn't work then that would be worth his while investigating why.

Comment: @dawg That isn't for a single quoted character, it is an ANSI C style string, and can contain as many characters as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use cut for situations like this, it's what it was designed to do.

Comment: Thank you Ed. Can you please explain me when and why to use cut vs awk? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Use `cut` when you want to print field(s) in the same order as they occurred in the input using a 1-character delimiter. Use `awk` for everything else. The reasons to do so are brevity and efficiency.

Answer (score -2):

You could also use bash built-ins if your string only contains characters from ASCII `0x20-0x7f` except backslash (\)`0x5c` (Note the caveats mentioned by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/17666) about dealing with shell variables):

```
s='1, servername, url, Properties, hostname, version, os, application server'
IFS=', ' read _ server _ <<<"$s"
echo "'$server'"
```

Output:

```
'servername'
```

Or by using positional parameters:

```
oIFS="$IFS"
export IFS=', '
set -- $s
echo $2
IFS="$oIFS"
```

Or:

```
function getserver() (
  export IFS=', '; set -- $1; echo $2
)
getserver "1, servername, url, Properties, hostname, version, os, application server"
```

Output:

```
servername
```